# ¿Cómo agregar el nombre de la variable a una lista de histogramas realizados con lapply?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy realizando los histogramas de un conjunto de variables y los quiero poner todos en una sola gráfica. Estoy empleando un ciclo para generar los histogramas y posteriormente los uno todos con la función `cowplot::plot_grid`. El problema es que en la gráfica final no aparecen los nombres de las variables (r5mn, r20mn, r5r20mn, r5r20r5mn, x5mn, x20mn, axmn, fresmn) sino una x (en el eje de las x) en todos los histogramas. Qué puedo hacer para que en cada histograma aparezca el nombre de la variable y no una x. La sintaxis que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
lista <-
  dataframe %>% 
  dplyr::select(r5mn, r20mn, r5r20mn, r5r20r5mn, x5mn, x20mn, axmn, fresmn) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) ggplot2::qplot(x, geom = "histogram"))

cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = lista)
```

Comment: Bienvenido DavidMB a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para indicar los nombres de variables puedes usar el parámetro `labels`, el nombre lo obtienes de la misma lista:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = lista, labels = names(lista))
```

También puedes probar la funcionalidad de facetado de `ggplot` que hace básicamente algo similar:

```
dataframe %>% 
  select(r5mn, r20mn, r5r20mn, r5r20r5mn, x5mn, x20mn, axmn, fresmn) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_histogram(aes(x=value), bins = 30) +
    facet_wrap(vars(name), ncol=4, scales="free")
```

Simplemente hay que transformar los valores en una tabla que sea `variable, valor` y a `facet_wrap()` solo hay que indicarle el nombre de la columna que tiene los nombres de cada variable.

Comment: Patricio, te agradezco tu ayuda, me fue de mucha utilidad.